# window leakage error not resolved after inserting data in MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, json

I am using localhost and MySQL database in my project. i have to insert data in database and then move to next intended activity. The Data is successfully added into database but after that app terminates with window leakage error in logcat.

Code:

```
class CreateNewCourier extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PackageDetail.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Adding Details..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Creating product
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_no", "120"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recp_name", recp_name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recp_no", recp_no));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("recp_adres", recp_adres));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pkg_name", pkg_name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pkg_quan", pkg_quan));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pickup_adres", pickup_adres));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pkg_type", pkg_type));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("veh_type", veh_type));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Breakable", Breakable));

                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                        "POST", params);

                // check log cat fro response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                   if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully created product
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                        // closing this screen

                       finish();
                    } else {

                        //failed to create product
                   }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();

                }

                    return null;
                }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                 //dismiss the dialog once done
               pDialog.dismiss();

            }
```

[image: Here is my logcat]

Comment: as the `log` says , your activity is either crashing or its because you are calling next activity before dismissing dialog resulting leaking of `window` which is in your case `pDialog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution , move this code to `onPostExecute()` after `pDialog.dismiss();`

```
if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen

                   finish();
                } else {

                    //failed to create product
               }
```

and also in `onDestroy` of activity add `pDialog.dismiss();` to avoid leakage

Comment: your welcome , m glad it worked for you happy coding